# How to return data at the end of all loops in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to return data when all the promises have been resolved but somehow the code is executing before the promises being resolve.

Here is the code I've tried but no luck.

```
     let promises = [];

return this.getAutoDealerByAutoGroupID(1).then(function (autoDealers) {
    //Iterate on dealers --- Map = foreach
    let i = 0;
    return autoDealers.map(function (dealer) {
        i++;

        let dealerObj = {
            sales: {
                new: [],
                used: [],
            },
            vehicleModel: {
                new: [],
                used: [],
            }
        };
        autoDealerID = dealer.id;
        dealerObj.dealer = dealer;

        //Iterate on dates
        //Last Week sales 
        lastweekDates.map((saleDate) => {

            salesFilter.saleDate = saleDate;
            salesFilter.autoDealerID = autoDealerID;
            salesFilter.vehicleTypes = ['New'];
            let sumSales = saleRepository.sumSales(salesWhere, salesFilter).then(function (resultSumSales) {
                let resultParseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resultSumSales));
                resultParseData = baseService.makeNullKeysToZero(resultParseData);
                resultParseData[0].sale_date = saleDate;

                dealerObj.sales.new.push(resultParseData[0]);
            });

            salesFilter.vehicleTypes = ['Used'];
            let sumSalesUsed = saleRepository.sumSales(salesWhere, salesFilter).then(function (resultSumSales) {
                let resultParseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resultSumSales));
                resultParseData = baseService.makeNullKeysToZero(resultParseData);
                resultParseData[0].sale_date = saleDate;

                dealerObj.sales.used.push(resultParseData[0]);
            });

            promises.push(sumSales);
            promises.push(sumSalesUsed);
        });
    });


    //Loop End
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function (result) {

        return dealersData;
    });


});
```

Also, Is this a right way to return such type of complex data ?

Comment: where is `promises` defined?

Comment: That's a giant block of code.  Can you distill it down to a smaller problem to ask about?  Plus doing a `promises.push()` inside a `.then()` handler will never work.  You need to push the parent promise that is available immediately, not some value that is only available some time later after your function returns.

Comment: Try running in strict mode and see what errors are reported.

Comment: @Mark_M, I have updated the code, Please check the promises defined.

Comment: @jfriend00, Yes I was thinking the same that some value might available after some time. Actually I need to return all dealersData at the end of the function. How to push the parent promise. Could you please provide some code base trick ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to return data at the end of all loops included nested loops but somehow last promise.all executing before all the above script to be executed.

Delivering the required data is something that will naturally happen if you get the overall pattern correct.

Consider :

```
function foo(arr) {
    return doSomethingAsync().then(function(result) {
        return Promise.all(arr.map(function (item) {
            return doSomethingElseAsync(result, item);
        }));
    });
}
```

`foo()` returns a promise that will deliver an array of results originating in `doSomethingElseAsync()`.

In essence, that's all you are trying to do. Your overall pattern needs to be no more complicated than that.

> Also, is this a right way to return such type of complex data?

No for a number of reasons, chiefly that you are expecting too much of the outer array `promises`. As it stands, the array is "shared" between an outer set and an inner set of promises, which is a recipe for chaos.

The real complexity in what you want to achieve lies in the gathering of dealer data, which involves several asynchronous function calls. With reference to the pattern above, this means that your innermost function will be many more lines, in which you should :

- use `.map()` properly in several places to create arrays of promises, each with its own `Promise.all()`.
- map `lastweekDates` separately for "new" and "used"; squeezing both into a single `.map()` just complicates matters
- have a "master" `Promise.all()` to aggregate the various asynchronous components
- return a `dealerObj` from the innermost function to deliver (eventually) the required array.

Here's the pattern fleshed out slightly more to show the kind of inner pattern required :

```
exports.getData = function (autoGroupId, startDate, endDate, givenDate) {
    return this.getAutoDealerByAutoGroupID(1)
    .then(function (autoDealers) {
        return Promise.all(autoDealers.map(function (dealer) {
            let newSalesPromise = Promise.all(lastweekDates.map(saleDate => {
                return saleRepository.sumSales(...) // with "new" parameter
                .then(...);
            }));

            let usedSalesPromise = Promise.all(lastweekDates.map(saleDate => {
                return saleRepository.sumSales(...) // with "used" parameter
                .then(...);
            }));

            let newVehicleModelsPromise = vehicleRepository.getVehicleModels(...)
            .then(vehicles => {
                return Promise.all(vehicles.map(function (vehicle) {
                    return saleRepository.countSales(...)
                    .then(...);
                }));
            });

            // this appears to be identical for all dealers, therefore could be moved outside autoDealers.map()
            let workingDaysPromise = workingDayRepository.getFilteredWorkingDays(workingDaysFilter)
            .then(...);

            // Here, use `Promise.all()` again to aggregate the individual data-delivering promises and create the desired dealerObj object
            return Promise.all([newSalesPromise, usedSalesPromise, newVehicleModelsPromise, workingDaysPromise])
            .then(function ([newSales, usedSales, newVehicleModels, workingDays]) { // deconstruct
                // construct and return the `dealerObj` object
                return {
                    'dealer': dealer,
                    'sales': { 'new': newSales, 'used': usedSales },
                    'vehicleModel': { 'new': newVehicleModels, 'used': [] }, // where does 'used' data come form?
                    'workingDays': workingDays
                };
            });
        }));
    });
}
```

Now you can have fun re-injecting your original code (or similar) at each `...`. You should (after some debugging I suspect) have a function that will return `Promise<Array<dealerobjects>>`.

Note that the need to `.push()` disappears completely in favour of returning data from `.then()` callbacks.

**EDIT**:

On the basis that ...

- `workingDayRepository.getFilteredWorkingDays(workingDaysFilter)` always gives the same result,
- `this.getAutoDealerByAutoGroupID(1)` and `workingDayRepository.getFilteredWorkingDays(workingDaysFilter)` can be executed in parallel (which seems reasonable)

... then `workingDayRepository.getFilteredWorkingDays(workingDaysFilter)` can be executed once, up-front, in a lightly modified version of the pattern, as follows :

```
exports.getData = function (autoGroupId, startDate, endDate, givenDate) {
    return this.getAutoDealerByAutoGroupID(1)
    .then(function (autoDealers) {

        let workingDaysPromise = workingDayRepository.getFilteredWorkingDays(workingDaysFilter)
        .then(...); // (moved)

        return Promise.all(autoDealers.map(function (dealer) {
            let newSalesPromise = Promise.all(lastweekDates.map(saleDate => {
                return saleRepository.sumSales(...) // with "new" parameter
                .then(...);
            }));

            let usedSalesPromise = Promise.all(lastweekDates.map(saleDate => {
                return saleRepository.sumSales(...) // with "used" parameter
                .then(...);
            }));

            let newVehicleModelsPromise = vehicleRepository.getVehicleModels(...)
            .then(vehicles => {
                return Promise.all(vehicles.map(function (vehicle) {
                    return saleRepository.countSales(...)
                    .then(...);
                }));
            });

            // Here, use `Promise.all()` again to aggregate the individual data-delivering promises and create the desired dealerObj object
            return Promise.all([newSalesPromise, usedSalesPromise, newVehicleModelsPromise, workingDaysPromise])
            .then(function ([newSales, usedSales, newVehicleModels, workingDays]) {
                // construct and return the `dealerObj` object
                return {
                    'dealer': dealer,
                    'sales': { 'new': newSales, 'used': usedSales },
                    'vehicleModel': { 'new': newVehicleModels, 'used': [] }, // where does 'used' data come form?
                    'workingDays': workingDays
                };
            });
        }));
    });
};
```

Comment: You know what you made my day :) I can understand it takes time to make the code that actually a live code so I am really appreciate your hard work. If we have mentor like you then every one will be a BOSS :) one more thing, how to move workingDaysPromise outside autoDealers.map() and return it ?

Comment: @Tariq, thank you for your very kind comments. I have added a modified version of the pattern above to show how `workingDays` can be gotten just once.

Comment: @Tariq, I've just edited the edit ;-) - first attempts was over-complicated and slightly wrong.

Comment: Man you are a legend :) This is what I wanted. Thanks. I have just a confusion and I am sure it would be last. What If I wanted to return data like return {
      'delaers': {
       'dealer': dealer,
       'sales': { 'new': newSales, 'used': usedSales },
       'vehicleModel': { 'new': newVehicleModels, 'used': usedVehicleModels }, 
       'workingDays': workingDays
      },
      'key': value,
      'key': value
     }

Comment: Two possible approaches (a) obtain values from data already gathered (you may need to adjust the `.then(...)` callbacks to deliver the data you want);
(b) add further `let xyzPromise = ...` expression(s), then add `xyzPromise` and `xyz` to the aggregator expression.
For `usedVehicleModels` it looks like you can assign `let vehicleModelsPromise = vehicleRepository.getVehicleModels(...);` then branch, ie `newVehicleModelsPromise = vehicleModelsPromise.then(...)` and `usedVehicleModelsPromise = vehicleModelsPromise.then(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for your approaches,  I have warped Promise.all(autoDealers.map(function (dealer) { to a new promise and return it with a new key and values and it works :) Everything seems fine now. Thanks for your kind support. Stay blessed.

Comment: Thanks Tariq, you too.  Good luck with your project.